# I want to use Interceptor in Angular that will display all the p-toast in angular, interceptor is working fine but toast is not visible

Tags: angular

I have used interceptor to show the toast errors or messages coming with the responses. Still the toast is not visible while I checked the interceptor is working fine. What is going wrong here?

I am sharing the code snippets .

**Interceptor**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpMessageInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private messages: MessageService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((event) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          let messages: string[] = (event as HttpResponse<any>).body.messages;
          if (messages && messages.length) {
            messages.forEach((message) =>
              this.messages.add({
                severity: 'success',
                detail: message,
                life: 20000,
              })
            );
          }
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          let response = err as HttpErrorResponse;
          let errors: string[] = response.error?.messages;
          console.log("ege" , errors);
          if (errors && errors.length) {
            errors.forEach((error) =>
              this.messages.add({
                severity: 'error',
                detail: error,
                life: 20000,
              })
            );
          } else {
            this.messages.add({
              severity: 'error',
              detail: response.statusText,
              life: 20000,
            });
          }
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ToastModule} from "primeng/toast";
import {RippleModule} from "primeng/ripple";
import {InputTextModule} from "primeng/inputtext";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {ButtonModule} from "primeng/button";
import {AvatarModule} from "primeng/avatar";
import {HttpClientModule , HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from "@angular/common/http";
import {MessageService} from "primeng/api";
import {OverlayPanelModule} from "primeng/overlaypanel";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FriendComponent } from './friendship/friend/friend.component';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './services/token.interceptor';
import { TieredMenuModule } from 'primeng/tieredmenu';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/menu';
import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages';
import { HttpMessageInterceptorService } from './services/http-message-interceptor.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToastModule,
    RippleModule,
    FormsModule,
    ButtonModule,
    AvatarModule,
    InputTextModule,
    OverlayPanelModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TieredMenuModule,
    MenuModule,
    MessagesModule,
    MenubarModule
    
  ],
  providers: [
    MessageService, {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpMessageInterceptorService,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have used message service as providers, I have also defined interceptor in app module, I have also used p-toast in app.component.html. Still not visible.

Tried this too

```
export class HttpMessageInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private messages: MessageService , private readonly changeDetectorRef : ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((event) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          let messages: string[] = (event as HttpResponse<any>).body.messages;
          if (messages && messages.length) {
            messages.forEach((message) =>
              this.messages.add({
                severity: 'success',
                detail: message,
                life: 20000,
              })
            );
          }
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          let response = err as HttpErrorResponse;
          let errors: string[] = response.error?.messages;
          console.log("ege",errors); // even this is not printing on doing changes 
          if (errors && errors.length) {
            errors.forEach((error) =>
              this.messages.add({
                severity: 'error',
                detail: error,
                life: 20000,
              })
            );
          } else {
            this.messages.add({
              severity: 'error',
              detail: response.statusText,
              life: 20000,
            });
          }
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      }),
      finalize(()=> this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges())
    );
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth.service";
import {UserProfileService} from "./services/user-profile.service";
import {UserProfile} from "./models/userProfile";
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import { TieredMenu } from 'primeng/tieredmenu';
import { OverlayPanel } from 'primeng/overlaypanel';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers:[MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  title = 'Outing';
  userProfile?: UserProfile;
  constructor(public route : Router,public authService:AuthService, private userProfileService:UserProfileService, public messageService: MessageService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userProfileService.getUserProfile().subscribe((userProfile)=>{
      this.userProfile=userProfile;
    });
  }

  signOutClicked($event: any) {
    $event.hide();
    this.userProfile = undefined;
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Signout Successfully!', sticky: true  });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.messageService.clear(); // Remove the toast manually
    }, 20000); 
    this.authService.logOut();
  }
  @ViewChild('mobileMenu') mobileMenu!: OverlayPanel;

  menuItems: MenuItem[] = [
    { label: 'Home', icon: 'pi pi-home', routerLink: '/home', routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true, class: 'active' }},
    { label: 'Outings', icon: 'pi pi-map-marker', routerLink: '/outing' },
    { label: 'Friends', icon: 'pi pi-users', routerLink: '/friendship' },
    { label: 'Expenses', icon: 'pi pi-dollar', routerLink: '/expenses' },
    
  ];

  toggleMobileMenu(event: Event) {
    this.mobileMenu.toggle(event);
  }

  closeMobileMenu() {
    if (this.mobileMenu) {
      this.mobileMenu.hide();
    }
  }  
  
  tier={
      'width':'8.5rem'
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace your toasterModule to ToasterModule.forRoot() into your app.module.ts file

Comment: you mean ToastModule? and if yes then where should i write this, while  importing

Comment: @JayPatel Actually I am using Primeng ToastModule,

for using forRoot() for this , it is giving me "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof ToastModule'.ts(2339)
"

Comment: does the Toast Messages work if you add it from another place (i.e. from AppComponent). Have you added `<p-messages>` in the Template of AppComponent?

Comment: I am using <p-toast> of Primeng, yes I have added p-toast in appcomponent

Comment: If I am directly using messageService without interceptor it is working and showing toast
like you can see, earlier i was showing toast at each api call
  signinUser() {
    this.authService.signinApi(this.signingInUser).subscribe((response: any) => {
       // some code
      },
      (errors) => {
       
       const error = errors.error.messages;
        if (error && error.length) {
          error.forEach((err : any) =>
            this.messageService.add({
              severity: 'error',detail: err,life: 20000
      }) );
     } 
      
      }
    );
  } @Zerotwelve

Comment: If you use as provider MessageService in the component, you **not** create a singleton service else a new instance of the service

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

Actually, I was including `MessageService` as providers in `AppComponent.ts`, So for using message service as interceptors I will need to remove `messageService` as providers in `AppComponent.ts`. As I removed it, it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the addMessage is not running in the NgZone and so the changeDetection is not triggered.

You could try to inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor and call it after adding all the messages:

```js
constructor(
  private messages: MessageService,
  private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}
```

```
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((event) => { /* ... */ }),
      catchError((err: any) => { /* ... */ }),
      finalize(() => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges())
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering friend!
But eariler atleast interceptor was working, but with these changes, even interceptor is not working, I tried having a console there

I am mentioning the changes in description

Comment: Can you put your console.log as first lines in the tap/catchError/finalize?